# AngularJS 400 bad request don't give any response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-status-code-400

I've searched on Google and stack overflow about similar / even same problems. But I'm new to this none of them gives me any idea of how can I fix up my code.

So, here is my script:

```
$http.post('/authlogin', {
    email: $scope.userdata.email,
    password: $scope.userdata.password
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status == 400) {
        $scope.errormsg = response.data;
    }
    if (response.status == 200) {
        window.location = '/admin';
    }
});
```

Everything is working fine for `200 OK` response. But whenever the login failed the API returns `400 Bad Request`. At this moment, the error looks like it is not even calling the anonymous function with the `response`. Most place a check for 400, 200, 201 etc. was okay & runs perfectly, but why not with 400.

Here is the error as shown in browser console by AngularJS (prettified & removed sensitive data):

```
Possibly unhandled rejection:
{
    "data": "Invalid email/password combination.",
    "status": 400,
    "config": {
        "method": "POST",
        "transformRequest": [null],
        "transformResponse": [null],
        "jsonpCallbackParam": "callback",
        "url": "/authlogin",
        "data": {
            "email": "####",
            "password": "***"
        },
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
        }
    },
    "statusText": "Bad Request"
}
```

I'm not a pro in angular.js, an explanation of this behavior and solution would be appreciated.

My target is to display an error message to user that is returned in `data`.

Comment: have you tried to add a error function to the then? ``.then(function(){ // success function}, function(){ console.log(arguments); // error function})``. then can take 1 argument to be function (success only) or 2 arguments to be function (success and error)

Comment: Are you using form submit to pass your data to server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise that is returned by `$http` is resolved by calling the first anonymous function. If a promise is rejected the second anonymous function is called. This should do the trick.

```
$http.post('/authlogin', {
    email: $scope.userdata.email,
    password: $scope.userdata.password
}).then(function(successCallback) {       
    if (successCallback.status == 200) {
        window.location = '/admin';
    }
}, function(errorCallback){
    if (errorCallback.status == 400) {
        $scope.errormsg = errorCallback.data;
    }
});
```

For more examples read the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

You can read more about promises [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Comment: OMG, @digijap you saved my day! Thanks for the explaination for this behavior.